# How to allow access a page from another php

Tags: php

how allow access a page from another page I have a page called info.php but i don't want no one to enter from browser and if they try the page will negate access, i want them to enter accessing from another page that activates the entrance for info.php

Comment: so what have you done so far?

Comment: nothing :( the problem is i know how to add code to page but not make a code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] when entering your "private page"...

It is the page that called the current page. Just check it on your "private" page, and if the referer is really the page you allow user access from, then display it. if not just display an error message...

http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.server.php

Hope it helps!